# SAS. Why "Jan 11 2002" == "88399", according to documentation?

Tags: date, sas

I was reading the [dates documentation](https://v8doc.sas.com/sashtml/lrcon/zenid-63.htm), but couldn't understand how SAS handled the dates:

On [SAS website](https://v8doc.sas.com/sashtml/lrcon/zenid-63.htm) they explain that `Jan 1 1961` is 366, which makes sense : this is the number of days from `Jan 1 1960`.

Further they convert `Jan 11 2002` into `88399` WHY ? This does not make any sense . The number of days from `Jan 1 1960` to `Jan 11 2002` is NOT 88399, it is around 16K !!!

**Where do they get the 88399 ?**

Thanks in advance !

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think it is either a typo in the documentation or a calculation mistake, and is supposed to be Jan 11, 2**2**02.

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=jan+1+1960+%2B+88399+days

FWIW, the [-67019 seems to be correct](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=days+between+july+4+1776+and+jan+1+1960) and the [correct value for Jan 11, 2002 is 15351](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=days+between+jan+1+1960+and+jan+11+2002).

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up for me. I had this question a long time ago, but was hesitating to ask . . I was sure that I misunderstand something and need to have more SAS exeperience. I could not imagine that SAS could have a type on their website .

Comment: Where there's a will, there's a way. And where there's a keyboard, there's a typo. :( Unfortunately for a lot of companies, documentation is an afterthought, often written by a single person or a small team, and honestly rarely checked with any degree of thoroughness. And yes, even when - or sometimes I feel like especially when - it involves an API that's at the core of their business. So sometimes it's just up to us to work together and find out the *real* truth, and hopefully you've just saved the next person a headache by asking this question.

Comment: (As someone that used to write SAS Documentation...) I would like to point out the link is to SAS v8, released about 15 years ago.  The current documentation has this fixed.  http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrcon/67885/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p1wj0wt2ebe2a0n1lv4lem9hdc0v.htm

Comment: I'd also add, SAS is _very_ good at making chnages to documentation when issues are raised to their attention via a ticket at support.sas.com - one of if not the best in the business at responding to customer requests (as they should be given the price).

Comment: Good to know at least SAS is on the ball. I've seen a lot of companies who are very much not so.